# N-Dimensional vector from scalar

Tags: vector

Is there a way in Mathematica to create an n-dimensional vector, where each element is a given scalar? I have tried the `Array` function, as the documentation center suggests for tensors, but it generates indexed values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayReshape[Range @ 6, {2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ArrayReshape[ConstantArray[1, 12], {2, 3, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Or

```
ConstantArray[1, {2, 3, 2}]
```

(Same output)